# Почему в профайлере не отображаются Awake и Start?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется несколько вызовов TryGet и GetComponent в Awake и Start. Хотел посмотреть их в профайлере но не нашел. Вбил в поиске имя скрипта, в котором происходит вызов, просмотрел весь график, но ничего не нашел. Переместил вызовы в Update, которые впоследствии нашлись в профайлере. Почему же Awake и Start не отображаются?

P.S. DeepProfiler включен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться встроенными инструментами, для отладки некоторых блоков кода

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Example()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("MyPieceOfCode");
        // Code to measure...
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
}
```

Это поможет вам, взят из источника: [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiling.Profiler.BeginSample.html)

Comment: @insolor это ссылка на офф. документацию, допускается.

Comment: @aepot не согласен. Если это фактически только ссылка без дополнительной полезной информации, то это скорее комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @insolor какая еще полезная информация? Зачем наоборот лишнюю информацию давать и путать. Там все легко и понятно, всего вызов двух методов, боже. Есть вопрос и конкретно ответ. Все, какая еще информация нужна? Это маразм, писать тут еще либо какую-то информацию!

Comment: @Alexey ну добавьте пару слов в ответ из той документации, это действительно не помешает.

Comment: @Alexey ссылка должна быть ссылкой на источник приведенной в ответе информации или ссылкой на дополнительную информацию, а не единственной информацией в ответе. Если убрать ссылку, то ответа фактически и нет. Такое вполне допустимо для комментариев, но ответы должны быть более-менее полноценными, содержать достаточное количество информации в себе, без необходимости ходить по ссылкам

Comment: @insolor кто и самое главное зачем будет убирать ссылку? Что значит 'а если убрать?'. А если убрать принцип, который вами управляет и вместо того чтобы заниматься действительно полезными вещами, вы прицепились к этому? Ответ дан, причем в ясной и максимально лаконичной форме. Ответ может быть и даже в одно слово. В этом разницы нет. Не возможно угодить вам, чтобы не сделать, как не написать! Вы будете стадом показывать свое превосходство и искать даже в самых тайных уголках ошибку. Или какие-то недочеты. Есть вопрос, есть и ответ.И он РЕШАЕТ ПРОБЛЕМУ.Слова в верхнер регистре прочтите много раз

Comment: Очень много эмоций. Просто почитайте справку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @insolor если он решает суть вопроса, может. А если нет, значит я не знаю что я делаю в этом отбитом сайте. Я пытаюсь помочь, и у меня это получается. Но наглость со стороны тех, кто заядло учит правила и демонстрирует свою лояльность со стороны администрации - не могу терпеть.

Comment: @insolor я понимаю, если бы там в источнике было море информации, куда не взглянь, как в photoshop ничего не разобрать. А там пару строк кода и описание. ВСЕ! Если это не разобрать, то тогда по факту я не знаю что еще может ему помочь.

Comment: @Alexey достаточно было бы сразу добавить в ответ один абзац текста из пары строк, и инцидент сразу был бы исчерпан. Вы видите во мне врага, а я просто стараюсь следить за качеством сайта, чтобы он не был просто набором ссылок (типа ссылка на код в вопросе, или еще хуже - фотография кода, и ссылка на решение в ответе). Я вижу, что вы отредактировали ответ, у меня больше никаких претензий нет.